# SPRING framework: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/invoice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitInvoice(HttpServletRequest request, 
            @RequestParam("clients") int clientId,
            @RequestParam("invoice_date") String invoice_date, 
            @RequestParam("invoice_due_date") String invoice_due_date, 
            @RequestParam("status") String status, 
            @RequestParam("payment_method") String payment_method, 
            @RequestParam("currency") String currency, 
            @RequestParam("description") String description, 
            @RequestParam("quantity") String quantity, 
            @RequestParam("price") String price, 
            @RequestParam("total") String lineTotal) {

        if(!hasRole(request, "ROLE_USER")){
            return "403";
        }

        long invoiceId = 0;

        DBManager.createInvoice(clientId, invoice_date, invoice_due_date, status, payment_method, currency);
        DBManager.invoiceDescription(invoiceId, description, quantity, price, lineTotal);



        return "redirect:/invoices/page/1";
    }
```

Database Manager Below

```
public static long createInvoice(
        int clientId, String invoice_date, String invoice_due_date, 
        String status, String payment_method, String currency){

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        long invoiceId = 0;

        //String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());


        String sql = "INSERT INTO invoice"
                + "(invoiceId, clientId, invoice_date, invoice_due_date, status, payment_method, currency) VALUES"
                + "(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {

            dbConnection = getDBConnection();

            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, clientId);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, invoice_date);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, invoice_due_date);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, status);
            preparedStatement.setString(5, payment_method);
            preparedStatement.setString(6, currency);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("You have successfully created an invoice record");

            PreparedStatement getLastInsertId = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
            ResultSet rs = getLastInsertId.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                invoiceId = rs.getLong("last_insert_id()");

                System.out.println("Last invoiceId inserted: " + invoiceId);

            }

        } catch (SQLException e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
        return invoiceId;
    }

public static void invoiceDescription(
        long invoiceId, String description, String quantity, 
        String price, String lineTotal){

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;


        //String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());


        String sql = "INSERT INTO invoice_description"
                + "(descId, invoiceId, description, quantity, price, total) VALUES"
                + "(NULL,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {

            dbConnection = getDBConnection();

            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);

            preparedStatement.setLong(1, invoiceId);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, description);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, quantity);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, price);
            preparedStatement.setString(5, lineTotal);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("You have successfully added descriptions to invoice");


        } catch (SQLException e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

I am getting the following message for the code above:

`'The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.'`.

I am trying to insert into multiple tables. If I remove `DBManager.invoiceDescription` it will insert the first part to the invoice table very well without errors, but when I add the `invoiceDescription` part, it doesn't insert anything. Please help :)

Comment: please add  stack trace of  error  you are getting!!!

Answer (score 1):

Error `"The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."` means that your request was not correctly formatted.

I see that all your request parameters are required, so if at least one of them is missing you'll get this error. Make sure that you are sending all your request parameters, or if you want sometimes to send some of them, you can make them not mandatory:

```
@RequestParam(value = "clients", required = false)
```

In this case if you make them all not mandatory, you can chose which params to send.